# Write non form data to xml using php

Tags: php, html

I am coding a video platform. When anyone sees the video and hit the like button the like should be incremented by one and should be written to xml file - I want to do this with php. And when the like symbol is clicked, the php should not be loaded but it should be executed.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<a href='#' onclick='doLike(id)'><i class='material-icons'        style='float:bottom'>thumb_up</i></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doLike(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "likup.php",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function(){alert('Cannot reach file');},
    success:
            function(){
                alert("Saved Successfully");
            }
});}
```

PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file = 'xml/shortfilm/filmname.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$xml->Shortfilm[0]->like= 2;
```

But I am still unable to achieve what I want.

Comment: At first you should send the ID of the mentioned video to your php code, meanwhile I think your problem is in your php code, so please write your php code more detailed.

Comment: Also, you should save your changes, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick='doLike(id)'
```

On click `doList(id)` will be called. What is `id`? Is it defined? You need to make sure that this parameter has the correct value. Your `doLike` does not send the `id` to the server. You need to send it, otherwise your server will not receive it. Your server, in turn should process the request and save the like into the xml.